Efficient algorithm for determining if a DAG exists
A directed graph can be constructed from a set of given graph nodes. Each graph node has an arbitrary number of sets of edges which can be empty and represented by a tree. Each tree node may contain 0 or more edges. Each set of edges can be derived by traversing the tree from the root down to a leaf and taking the union of all encountered tree node’s sets of edges. The number of edge sets for a given graph node is equal to the number of leafs in its tree. What is an efficient (should reduce time complexity to a minimum before reducing space complexity) algorithm that can determine whether a Directed Acyclic Graph exists from the given graph nodes and if not, report a set of graph nodes that contribute to an unbreakable cycle?
Example 1:
{ A } // node definition
-> // points to neighbors
[] // neighbor tree
[A], [B]

{ B }
->
[A]

This creates an unbreakable cycle because node B must point to node A, and node A may point to itself or node B, both of which create a cycle. A may be returned as the “problem node”.
Example 2:
{ A }
->
[]
[A], []

{ B }
->
[]
[A], [B]

This set of nodes contains an acyclic directed graph. A may point to no nodes while B points to A. The set of edges that create this DAG may be returned.
I have looked into cycle detection algorithms and strongly connected components and can solve the problem for the simple case where every node has exactly 1 set of edges. However, I am not sure how to approach it when each node has multiple possible edge sets.

Normally you (attempt to) do a topological sort. If that succeeds, the result is a DAG. Two common ways to do that are a depth-first search or Kahn's algorithm. If memory serves either is normally O(V + E).

Do you have a separate tree for each node or one tree for all nodes?

@n.m.couldbeanAI each graph node has its own tree

So you basically have a bunch (tree1_nleaves * tree2_nleaves * ,,, * treeM_nleaves) of ways to form a graph, and you want to find out if one of these ways results in a DAG?

@n.m.couldbeanAI Yes, except n can also vary between each tree

Please [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] with: some sample data that demonstrates the problem; and the expected output for your sample data. If your DAGs can pick paths from different "trees" then you appear to need to merge all the trees into a single forest and then any edges can be picked (independent of which tree they came from) and by merging the sets of edges for each tree into a super-set then the problem reduces to only a single set per vertex; ...

but if you can only follow paths from within a single "tree" then the problem is just to find DAG within each tree (so treat each tree separately) and you don't need to worry about crossing between trees.
